# Streaming live desktop video to a web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video-streaming, cdn, live-streaming

I'm looking to find a way to stream a user's desktop LIVE (through some piece of software, such as [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/)) to a web application.

I'm assuming I should use a CDN to get the live streamed video to my web application, but how (and what software should I use) to get the user's desktop to a streaming service? Should I use a service such as Red5 or an AWS service? Or if only a few viewers are using it, should I host the service myself?

Although I have built my share of web applications, I have never dealt with live media streaming before, and I would appreciate any assistance anyone could lend.

Comment: @Arslan Ali Hi, How are you? Have you implemented the video live streaming using rails. I also have to implement it for my college project can you help me how to do it. Basically from where to start.

Comment: @SourabhBanka I'm only the editor of this question. You need to get to the others for this, or ask it as a question on SO.

Answer (score 5):

**By far the best resource for video on Rails is [OpenTok](http://tokbox.com/opentok/)**

Our own demo here: http://bvc-video.herokuapp.com/broadcasts/1

--

**Streaming**

Video **streaming** is a tough one

The problem is really dependent on what you're trying to stream. If it's "live" video - I.E captured & sent directly to the viewers, you'll *have* to use some sort of server to process the video.

Although I don't have huge experience with this, the main issue we've found is the compression / distribution of the feed. It's actually very simple to acheive video streaming on iOS - all the software / hardware is the same (just use the same API / drivers)

This often negates the requirement for a central server, although it's highly recommended (almost required) for many cases. Problems arise when you try and beam to multiple clients on multiple systems; as you'll run into compatibility issues

--

**Solutions**

The solutions we've found are thus:

> - The most stable part of the app is to take the stream & send to a server
> - The wizardry will then be to beam that stream to multiple clients
> - The way to do this is typically to use a flash widget & pull the stream from the server

[WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) is becoming the standard ([OpenTok](http://tokbox.com/opentok/) is built on this)

I'm not sure about video compression / distribution. [Akami](http://www.akamai.com/hdonline) is an industry heavyweight, but I've never used it. [Brightcove](https://www.brightcove.com/en/) too

Comment: Thank you so much for all this information. I'm on mobile, so forgive me if my response isn't long winded. I think I definitely will need to use a streaming service to process the video. Akami and Brightcove can do this? Do you have any suggestions from streaming from a desktop to the video processing service? What software can I use to get the live video to the service? Thank you so much!

Comment: The "desktop" stream will have to be sent to a web service of some sort. Typically, you'd do this directly through the browser, but if you're using a native application, you'll need a service endpoint to send it to. I can't speak for Akami or Brightcove as I've never used them. I know a company who does & I could ask their advice if you need it?